# Can I use the same value for name and id in two different elements?

Tags: html

Can I use the same value for name and id in two different elements like below?

```
<label for="fromAccount"> From Account <labe/>
<div id="fromAccount">
<select name="fromAccount">
...
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Will this impact any accessibility standard?

Comment: you can but I don't think it'll work like desired. `for` should be bound to `action elements` not divs...

Comment: Thank you @RokoC.Buljan. This div actually is programmed as an action element only.

Comment: by action elements i mean Form Action Elements. Not DIVs. I don't know what's you're actually up to with that HTML... but LABEL will not focus the DIV when selected.

Comment: Thanks, @RokoC.Buljan. The role of this div is a button and it actually opens a popup with a select list. However, moving the id to the select element from div is working much better. Still waiting on some ADA test results though. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

yes because, you can use them with css this way:

```
class's use .fromAccount{}
name's use input[name="fromAccount"] { }
id's use #fromAccount{}
for's use input[for="fromAccount"] { }
```

and in javascript you could call them with:

```
class's use var x = document.getElementByClass("fromAccount");
name's use var x = document.getElementsByName("fromAccount");
id's use var x = document.getElementsById("fromAccount");
```

> This could be done for multiple lanuages with different conventions.

but HTML it self does not complain because it's a script and 
there are no compilations. That being said it's not a good coding conversion because it make you code messy.

Comment: HTML is script? No, that would mean that HTML can act and make decisions like JavaScript does.

Comment: my bad I meant a text :)